# OSX logs me out when inactive

Tags: macos

I have a strange issue with my MacBook Pro (6,2 OS X 10.6.8). When I leave the laptop for some time, let's say 30 minutes, I find only the log in screen.

I think it did not reboot. It just logged me off. Luckily some programs reject to be closed (that's annoying too, but different story) an I find a dialog that tells me application X prevented logout.

I am aware of the system setting to automatically log the user off. It is not active. I checked the GUI a hundred times.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have run into a weird bug here. For the time being, you could set the "Log out after x minutes of inactivity" to a really high number or you could download this little utility named caffeine, which prevents your Mac from going in to sleep for a specified time (including "infinity"): http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225

Comment: +1 for Caffeine, I use it every day... it only seems tangentially related to this problem, though.

Comment: Just when I thought my macbook finally got some self healing capabilities - it happened again. Will have a look and report back soon.